# mongoose query using sort and skip on populate is too slow

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using an ajax request from the front end to load more comments to a post from the back-end which uses NodeJS and mongoose. I won't bore you with the front-end code and the route code, but here's the query code:

```
Post.findById(req.params.postId).populate({
    path: type, //type will either contain "comments" or "answers"
    populate: {
        path: 'author',
        model: 'User'
    },
    options: {
        sort: sortBy, //sortyBy contains either "-date" or "-votes"
        skip: parseInt(req.params.numberLoaded), //how many are already shown
        limit: 25 //i only load this many new comments at a time.
    }
}).exec(function(err, foundPost){
    console.log("query executed"); //code takes too long to get to this line
    if (err){
        res.send("database error, please try again later");
    } else {
        res.send(foundPost[type]);
    }
});
```

As was mentioned in the title, everything works fine, my problem is just that this is too slow, the request is taking about 1.5-2.5 seconds. surely mongoose has a method of doing this that takes less to load. I poked around the mongoose docs and stackoverflow, but didn't really find anything useful.

Comment: How many documents are in posts, comments, answers collections? I think there are indexes missing in comments, answers collections on fields pointing to post. And why query answers and comments through the post, you could query them directly with postId? Then you would make one query less.

Comment: what do you meant by indexes missing ?

Comment: I mean that if you have many documents in MongoDB collections and are filtering or sorting them by some fields and the fields don't have indexes then the queries will be slow. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/

Comment: if I understand correctly you mean that for example, the query sorts comments by "-votes.upVotesNumber", but some comments don't have a "votes.upVotesNumber" field ? because that's not the case, all comments and answers have a default of Date.now for "date" and default of 0 for "votes.upVotesNumber"

Comment: No, that's not a problem when some of the documents don't have all the fields. Have you created indexes for fields that you use in sorting and the fields that connect answers and comments to post?

Comment: no, that I have not done. I'll do that now. thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using skip-and-limit approach with mongodb is slow in its nature because it normally needs to retrieve all documents, then sort them, and after that return the desired segment of the results.

What you need to do to make it faster is to define indexes on your collections.
According to MongoDB's official documents:

> Indexes support the efficient execution of queries in MongoDB. Without indexes, MongoDB must perform a collection scan, i.e. scan every document in a collection, to select those documents that match the query statement. If an appropriate index exists for a query, MongoDB can use the index to limit the number of documents it must inspect.
>   -- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/

Using indexes may cause increased collection size but they improve the efficiency a lot.

Indexes are commonly defined on fields which are frequently used in queries. In this case, you may want to define indexes on `date` and/or `vote` fields.

---

Read mongoose documentation to find out how to define indexes in your schemas:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes